# VB6 getting the combobox index to make an insert when the combo shows another field

Tags: sql, combobox, vb6, adodb

I need to use a combobox Id to make a sql insert and my combo only display the field "Name" of the table, and I kinda needed the field "Id" to make the insert, just like selectedValue on VB.NET

btw here's my code (VB6) to the call of the combobox select

```
Public Sub chamaCombo()
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsCombo As New ADODB.recordset

Dim conString As String

    constring="Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=MySv;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
con.Open conString

rsCombo.Open "Select * from tbdClient", con, adOpenDynamic

Do While rsCombo.EOF <> True
cmb_client.AddItem rsCombo("Name").Value
cmb_client.ItemData(cmb_client.NewIndex) = rsCombo("IdClient").Value

txt_idclient.Text = rsCombo("IdClient").Value 'trying to pass to a txt but its no use

rsCombo.MoveNext




Loop



End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would declare a parallel collection that holds the value of the index and keyed by the SQL ID.  Your code could look like this:

```
Private mCol As New Collection    

Public Sub chamaCombo()
Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rsCombo As New ADODB.recordset

Dim conString As String

    constring="Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=MySv;Database=MyDb;Trusted_Connection=yes"
con.Open conString

rsCombo.Open "Select * from tbdClient", con, adOpenDynamic

Do While rsCombo.EOF <> True
cmb_client.AddItem rsCombo("Name").Value
mCol.Add("K_" & CStr(cmb_client.NewIndex), rsCombo("IdClient").Value)

rsCombo.MoveNext

Loop

End Sub

Private cmb_client_Click()
    Dim ID As String
    ' Don't forget to test the ListIndex for a invalid value (ex: -1)
    ID = mCol("K_" & CStr(cmb_client.ListIndex))
    MsgBox ID
End Sub
```

Remember to clear the collection the same time where you are clearing the items on the combo box!